Angular - NGRX signal stores - duplicate injections
In an NGRX signal store,
If I need access to a service inside both the withComputed and withMethod blocks, I currently have to inject the same service in each.
Is there a way of making the service accessible to the entire signal store without having to inject the service twice?

One approach is to create a class property in the signal store class to hold the reference to the service. Then, use this property in both withComputed and withMethod blocks

How do you do that? The class has to be in the signalstore... wouldn't that throw an error though, as it expects only withComputed, withMethod, etc. blocks?

No, it is perfectly fine to inject the dependency for each block, as you are injecting the same instance, so no worries there.
However, injecting a service inside a withComputed block seems a little unusual. Instead, you could modify your store in a way that eliminates the dependency on the service for withComputed block (the service shouldn't handle state management anymore!). This way, in the withComputed block, you would only depend on the store values.

Thank you. The only reason I have the service on the withComputed block is because I have a function that flattens a nested object, about 20 lines of code, so I put that in a service, and call the function inside the withComputer block, for different computed properties. I tested it yesterday, though, and the withComputed block doesn’t trigger when the signal inside it changes. (The signal is inside the utility function inside the block, but computed should still trigger) I tried to debug for 2 hours and gave up. It’s either an ngrx or angular bug…or maybe by design :(
